# LSTM - RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-tuner

I am trying to use keras tuner to tune an LSTM neural network to detect if an article is a fake news or not, using a kaggle dataset.
However, I keep getting this error: RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model
I have also tried to use the RandomSearch rather than the BayesianOptimization, but still getting the same type of error.

This is the code:

'''

```
def build_model(hp): 
    voc_size=5000
    embedding_vector_features=40
    model = Sequential([
                        Embedding(
                            voc_size, 
                            embedding_vector_features, 
                            input_length = sent_length 
                        ), 
                        AlphaDropout(
                            rate = hp.Choice(
                                'dropout_1_rate', 
                                values=[0.3, 0.5], 
                                default=0.3
                                )
                            ),
                        LSTM(
                            units = hp.Int(
                                'LSTM_1_units', 
                                min_value=100, 
                                max_value=300, 
                                step=32, 
                                default=128
                                ), 
                            activation = hp.Choice(
                                'LSTM_1_activation', 
                                values=['relu', 'selu']
                                ), 
                            kernel_initializer='lecun_normal' 
                        ),
                        AlphaDropout(
                            rate = hp.Choice(
                                'dropout_2_rate', 
                                values=[0.3, 0.5], 
                                default=0.3
                                )
                        ),
                        LSTM(
                            units = hp.Int(
                                'LSTM_2_units',
                                 min_value=100, 
                                 max_value=300, 
                                 step=32, 
                                 default=128
                                 ), 
                            activation = hp.Choice(
                                'LSTM_2_activation', 
                                values=['relu', 'selu']
                                ), 
                            kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
                        ),
                        AlphaDropout(
                            rate = hp.Choice(
                                'dropout_3_rate', 
                                values=[0.3, 0.5], 
                                default=0.3
                                )
                        ),
                        Dense(
                            units = 1, 
                            activation = 'sigmoid', 
                            kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
                            )
                      ])
    
    model.compile(
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.Nadam(
            hp.Choice(
                'learning_rate', 
                values=[1e-2, 1e-3]
                )
            ),
        loss = 'binary_crooentropy', 
        metric = ['accuracy']
            )
    
    return model 

tuner_search = BayesianOptimization(build_model, 
                                objective='val_accuracy', 
                                max_trials=3, 
                                seed=42, 
                                directory='output',
                                project_name='Fake News Classifier'
)
```

'''

When I try to run this code I get the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
Invalid model 0/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-18-fe84fe0afbca>", line 62, in build_model
    kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 223, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 660, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

Invalid model 1/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-18-fe84fe0afbca>", line 62, in build_model
    kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 223, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 660, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

Invalid model 2/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-18-fe84fe0afbca>", line 62, in build_model
    kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 223, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 660, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

Invalid model 3/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-18-fe84fe0afbca>", line 62, in build_model
    kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 223, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 660, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

Invalid model 4/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_1 will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-18-fe84fe0afbca>", line 62, in build_model
    kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 223, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 660, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

Invalid model 5/5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-18-fe84fe0afbca>", line 62, in build_model
    kernel_initializer='lecun_normal'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 223, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 660, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py in build(self, hp)
    103                 with maybe_distribute(self.distribution_strategy):
--> 104                     model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
    105             except:

19 frames

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py in build(self, hp)
    111                 if i == self._max_fail_streak:
    112                     raise RuntimeError(
--> 113                         'Too many failed attempts to build model.')
    114                 continue
    115 

RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model.
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Actual error is `ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`. Full shape received: (None, 128)

LSTM layer expects input shape inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]

I could reproduce your issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-160c5e8d5d9a> in <module>()
      2 inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 8])
      3 lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
----> 4 output = lstm(inputs)
      5 print(output.shape)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    217                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
    218                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 219                          str(tuple(shape)))
    220     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    221       ndim = x.shape.rank

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 8)



Working code snippet 

import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(32, 4)
```